# Call a new onCreateInputView()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-service, android-input-method

I have to recall onCreateInputView because I have two skins of keyoards and I want to set it if a value is on preferences.
Now I can get this only restart application process, because I have a switch at the start of the onCreateInputView(), but after inflated, I cannot change this dinamically..

```
if (mKeyboardView2 != null) {
        mKeyboardView2.closing();
        mInputView2.invalidate();
        mInputView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((ViewGroup)mInputView2.getParent()).removeView(mInputView2);
```

Maybe with a onDestroy() of service? (but from preferenceactivity I cannot do this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a specific method to set a view.